# if condition is true but still jumping on else

Tags: php

I have created a login script using php and ajax. The password I echo the values and in return i found textbox value and database value to be same, but still its jumping to else statement. I am unable to figure out the problem with the code or what else I am doing wrong. May be one of you can see if anything wrong in my code

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass     = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $pass     = md5($pass);

    $check  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if($result == 1) {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
        $password_check = $data[2]; 

        if($password_check == $pass) {
            $_SESSION['uid']  = $data[0];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $data[3];
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='message'>Invalid Password</div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<div class='message'>Username/Password did not matched</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Adding `.`s might help us to read problem properly. And you explain the issue properly?

Comment: I am really sorry for the mistake but in my writings?

Comment: Please check now issue is i explained simple that if($password_check == $pass) { this statement is true then why it is jumping to else statement

Comment: Have you echoed $password_check and $pass to see if they are the same?

Comment: Check if `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$pass'` returns the correct record.

Comment: @DevinGray yes I echoed both. And both are same but coming in next line this would be a problem ? as  $password_check and $pass echoed in the next line as i did not put any br though ?

Comment: @Sougata Let me check

Comment: $check  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$pass'");
  echo $result = mysqli_num_rows($check); result 1

Comment: @MarkAlan that will not be a problem. Let me run a quick server and check this code

Comment: Probably an aside, but why do a db escape of the password when you aren't sending it?  Surely that should happen after the hash on select or insert.

Comment: What do you mean by coming in next line?  Do the passwords vary because one has a line break appended or prepended to it?